# How to get maximum number of nodes and ppn in PBS

Tags: linux, terminal, pbs

How can I query maximum number of nodes and maximum number of "processors per node" (ppn) of workstation in PBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer is for Torque, other PBS systems may vary.

If you look at the output of the pbsnodes command you can determine the number of nodes and the amount of ppn each has. pbsnodes output looks like

```
node
np = X
... more information ...
```

The top line is the host's name and the np = X tells you the ppn for that node.

To quickly determine the number of nodes in the system, you can execute something like:

```
pbsnodes -l all | wc -l
```

In short, the pbsnodes command will tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your 'maximum number of "processors per node" (ppn)' question run this command:

`pbsnodes | grep np | awk '{print $3}' | sort -nr | head -n1
64`

P